# Обновляление переменной без перезагрузки страницы на Flask

Tags: python, django, flask

К примеру, есть такой код:

```
from flask import Flask
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    x = random.randint(0,100)
    return 'X = {}'.format(x)

app.run(debug=True)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы значение "x" постоянно изменялось без перезагрузки страницы? Сейчас нужный результат можно получить только постоянно нажимая "F5".

Comment: используйте javascript, чтобы общаться с сервером, не перегружая страницу. [Streaming data with Python and Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13386681/4279)

Comment: пример: http://demo-server-sent-events.herokuapp.com/

Comment: да, тут понадобится ajax запрос